# What does the tag <action> of a receiver do?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have been working on an app that needs to use an `AlarmManager` and a `BroadcastReceiver`.

What I have seen on the internet is that I need an **action** which is inside the receiver in the `Manifest` and also has to be called in the code for my app to be able to perform some task. What I have seen is that tutorials just show what this action should look like in your `Manifest`.

My question is, what is the function of the **action**? Is it a key to perform an action, a variable, a value?

For example, the code below:

```
<receiver android:name="com.domain.app.">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.XYZ" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: In addition to Dougs answer, see here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_CHOOSER

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The action in a broadcast is the primary way to define what a broadcast means between the sender and receiver.  Think of it like a "type" of broadcast.  Typically the action is a verb describing something that took place.  The action helps receiving apps filter the kind of broadcasts they wish to receive.  In your example the app is declaring that it wants to receive broadcasts of the type given, but no others.

Comment: so, its kinda in some ways, like a tag or a favorite of a receiver. the action is the i guess the 'adjective' of the receiver. like, for example, 'updating' receiver or a 'launching' receiver